# Fast way to invoke generic method with type known at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I´m creating some instances of types that I do not know during compile-time. For this approach I searched for an alternative way then using `Activator.CreateInstance` because the number of instances may increase heavily during development. I found [this](https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/dont-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions/) post for fast creation of those instances. The only problem I have is that I do not know the actual type to create instances from during compile-time. Of course I could use `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(myType)` and afterwards use `method.Invoke` to invoke the received method. But as I read within the previously mentioned post calling `Invoke` on constructors takes much time, so I wondered if this also applies to usual methods.

Thus it would be quite ambivalent to search for a fast approach for constructing an instance of a type but not for the best solution to receive this type. So is there a similar (probably also using Expression-trees)?

Some code for EDIT:

```
public delegate T ObjectActivator<T>(params object[] args);

public class Test 
{

    public object create(Type t) 
    {
        // get the default-constructor
        ConstructorInfo ctor = t.GetConstructors().First();
        // pass the type to the generic method
        MethodInfo method = typeof(GenericTypeFactory).GetMethod("GetActivator").MakeGenericMethod(t);
        Func<ConstructorInfo, Delegate> getActivator = // howto point to the GetActivator-method by using the generic methodInfo from above         
    }
}

class GenericTypeFactory {
    public static ObjectActivator<T> GetActivator<T>(ConstructorInfo ctor) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do the same for method/property invocation - caching, compiled expressions, and if really adventurous manual `Reflection.Emit`.

Comment: Use the DLR to call a generic method. After you construct your object, store it as type `dynamic` and pass that to the generic method.

Comment: Side note: consider replacing "dynamic" with "known at run-time" in title to avoid confusion with `dynamic` (if indeed it is the case).

Comment: Can you give a conseptual example? And describe your actual use case?

Comment: Im guessing the best approach would some sort of (abstract) factory class...

Comment: Not knowing the type until runtime is the entire point of generics.  Why you'd intentionally make it slow with Reflection is hard to guess, that's the opposite of using generics.

Comment: By an example i ment something that demonstrates what you are trying to do and why. Not how are you going to reimplement the Activator class....

Comment: @HansPassant Well, I do not have a generic type argument (let´s call it T), I do have a type-param (see in the code). Thus I do not know how to pass that param to the generic method by not using reflection (since as you said its quite slow).

Answer (score 1):

Keep a dictionary from `Type` to a generated `Action<...>` that invokes your method quickly. The call overhead then is a dictionary lookup which is much less than a Reflection based invocation.

Comment: The question is more on how to build this dictionary (esp. the actions/funcs within it).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Any concrete problems? That should be documented many times on SO or other places. Create the expression tree corresponding to `(object obj) => GenericMethod<ConcreteType>((ConcreteType)obj)`. Write this in C# and use a decompiler to see what such a tree looks like.